# How to use wget to download in certain directory

Tags: wget, google-colaboratory

I want to download img from url using wget in colab

```
!wget [url] -p dir
```

the problem is whatever dir is it is always downloaded in the root

This is how I mounted drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('content')
```

when I list

```
!ls
```

I get

> content and the img downloaded

and when I list inside the desired dir nothing is downloaded there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-P` (uppercase), not `-p` (lowercase).

Here's an example:
[image]

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jXvNLLICzTJrQRadQyxwB9htQg_MkNcx

Answer (score 1):

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

!wget https://ai2-semanticscholar-cord-19.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/historical_releases/cord-19_2021-11-15.tar.gz -p /content/drive/MyDrive/postdoc/cord/
```

Comment: Can you offer an explanation of what you're doing here?

Comment: I tried ShainaRaiza's answer. No error but I can not see the file in the folder. I can see it using `ls` but physically, the file is not there. How can I see the physic of the file?

Comment: You need to give a path first, using cd command to see it physically at a location. In drive otherwise it will go on run time and be terminated later.